# Set Functions: Monotonicity and Sub-additivity are Independent?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is also asked in MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/278809, with confirmation of proposal in a comment.

I'm trying to untangle the relationship between monotone and sub-additive functions, and would like **confirmation or correction on the proposition that monotonicity and sub-additivity are independent**..

If $\mu$ is a set function mapping some collection $\mathscr B$ of subsets of $X$ to $[0, \infty]$ then

$\mu$ is *monotone* if for $A, B \in \mathscr B $ and $A \subset B$ then $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$

$\mu$ is *sub-additve* if for $A, B$ and $A \cup B \in \mathscr B $ then $\mu(A \cup B) \le \mu(A) + \mu(B)$

Proposition: monotonicity and sub-additive are independent. Proof by example. Let $\mathscr B $ be the powerset of {$a, b$} (so, $\mathscr B $ has the structure of an algebra) and $\mu$ take the values $\mu(\emptyset) = 0; \mu(\{a\}) = 1 ; \mu(\{b\}) = 1 ; \mu(\{a, b\}) = 0 $ or $3 $

Then for $\mu(\{a, b\}) = 0 $,  $\mu$ is sub-additive $\mu(\{a, b\}) = 0 \le 2 = \mu(\{a\}) + \mu(\{b\}) $, but not monotone $\{a\} \subset \{a, b\}$ but $1 = \mu(\{a\}) > 0 = \mu(\{a, b\})$

While for $\mu(\{a, b\}) = 3 $,  $\mu$ is monotone $\{a\} \subset \{a, b\}$ and $1 = \mu(\{a\}) < 3 = \mu(\{a, b\})$, but not sub-additive $\mu(\{a, b\}) = 3 > 2 = \mu(\{a\}) + \mu(\{b\}) $

(I found this particularity confusing since it seems that finitely monotone $\implies$ finitely sub-additive and countably monotone $\implies$ countably sub-additive. It appears that monotone (as defined above) is of a somewhat different nature to finitely monotone).

Comment: Now posted also at MathOverflow: [Set Functions: Monotonicity and Sub-additivity are Independent?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/278809). I think [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice, one of things mentioned there is that you should link to other copies of the question. Of course, some of other discussion about [meta-tag:cross-posting] might be of interest, too.